# Posting object containing interface with Http Client method Post As Json Async

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, httpclient

[image]

public interface IJobQueryModel
    {
    }

```
public class JobGoolgeAnalyticsQueryModel:IJobQueryModel
{
public string prop1 {get;set}
}

public class JobGoogleAdwordsQueryModel:IJobQueryModel
{
public string prop1 {get;set}
}

public class JobModel
{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public IList<IJobQueryModel> JobQueryModelList {get;set;}
}
```

When i post **JobModel** object, the interface having concrete type objects that are **JobGoolgeAnalyticsQueryModel** or  **JobGoogleAdwordsQueryModel**
give me empty List of **JobQueryModelList** in **JobModel**

Comment: Why you are doing in this way. Instead you can just use IList<object>

Comment: @PowerStar because in that way I won't be able to cast it on receiving end, when i try to GetType() it gives me Name = "JObject" FullName = "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject". I want proper type so that i should no in which concrete type to cast

Comment: Because an interface cannot be initialized.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have tried changing interface to class as well, same result

Comment: Do you mean you change it to `public IList<JobGoolgeAnalyticsQueryModel> JobQueryModelList { get; set; }`? If so and your sending the data in the correct format it will bind to your properties But the data in your image does not look right - its starts with double braces `{{` (and your code needs to be in the question - not images of it)

Comment: @StephenMuecke No I Chaged IJobQueryModel interface to class and tried to post data, it gives me list of Empty IJobQueryModel models, however, I had filled it with my concrete objects i-e JobGoogleAdwordsQueryModel and JobGoolgeAnalyticsQueryModel